# Linux mount nfs disk from windows machine

Tags: linux, windows, nfs

I want to mount a disk from a Windows machine (D:) to an Oracle Linux machine. How can I do this? I know a command but it is wrong.

```
mount -t nfs ipadressOfWindows:/D:/ /u02/
```

Comment: On the Linux system, what does `showmount -e ipaddressOfWindows` say? It should list all the filesystems that the Windows system is willing to export.

Comment: Is the disk shared via NFS or via CIFS (Samba)?  What is the output of the command you tried?

Comment: [root@db1 ~]# showmount -e 192.168.10.248
Export list for 192.168.10.248:
@MarkPlotnick

Comment: That may mean the Windows system isn't configured to export any NFS filesystems. Does `rpcinfo -p ipaddressOfWindows` show any output? It should show portmap, nfs, and possibly a few other services. Do you know whether the Windows system is running NFSv3 or NFSv4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try showmount -e ipaddressOfWindows |grep -i \D:\
```

You will get the netgroups , Make server or machine a members of those netgroups. The mount command will depend on the type is it CIFS or NFS ?

Comment: result is empty